# How to use conditional Statements in Jenkins 'Options' block

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am trying to set a timeout on a Jenkins pipeline job based on a variable.

I have got something like this:

```
    pipeline {
        agent any
        options {
            timeout(time:6, unit:'HOURS')
    
        }
}
```

I will like this timeout to be set only when a variable is true. Something like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        if (timerCause) {
            timeout(time:6, unit:'HOURS')
       }
    }
}
```

I can't do this with `if` or `when` statements in the options block. Any pointers would be great. Thanks :)

Comment: Is it a Pipeline- or a Stage-level options block?

Comment: @criztovyl It's a Pipeline option block.

Comment: For a Pipeline-level you might be able to use a `script` block in combination with a `properties` step.

Answer (score 1):

How about you set a default value if the flag is not set.

```
def flag = false
def to = Integer.MAX_VALUE
if(flag) {
    to = 500
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
         timeout(time:to, unit:'SECONDS')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what a `timerCause` is, and not willing to guess, I'd just recommend the ternary operator:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        timeout(time: timerCause ? 6 : 9999, unit:'HOURS')
    }
}
```