# How to use conditions in Jenkins multibranch declarative pipeline "options" block?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I would like to configure the `Office365` options to run based on the branch, since the URL of each branch is different

```
options {   office365ConnectorWebhooks([[notifyBackToNormal: true, notifyFailure: true, notifySuccess: true, notifyUnstable: true, url: '']]) }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use conditional Statements in Jenkins 'Options' block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72731557/how-to-use-conditional-statements-in-jenkins-options-block)

Comment: No it doesnt, i have two different office365 url's, i need to make the options a conditional options block to run if it is a specific branch, just like env.Branch_NAME

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to create simple variable before pipeline {} block and set its value conditionally.

```
def webHookUrl

if ("${env.BRANCH_NAME}".startsWith("PR-")) {
  webHookUrl = "https://your-first-url"
} else {
  webHookUrl = "https://your-second-url"
}

pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'my_node'
  }
  options {
    office365ConnectorWebhooks([[startNotification: true,
                                 notifySuccess: true,
                                 notifyAborted: true,
                                 notifyNotBuilt: false,
                                 notifyUnstable: true,
                                 notifyFailure: true,
                                 notifyBackToNormal: true,
                                 notifyRepeatedFailure: true,
                                 url: "$webHookUrl",
                                 name: "Webhook Name"
                                ]])
  }

  stages {.....}
```

Moreover, if you want to get full control it could be achieved by some wrapper class like this (in declarative style):

```
class WebhooksOptions {
  // default values
  Boolean startNotification = true
  Boolean notifySuccess = true
  Boolean notifyAborted = true
  Boolean notifyNotBuilt = true
  Boolean notifyUnstable = true
  Boolean notifyFailure = true
  Boolean notifyBackToNormal = true
  Boolean notifyRepeatedFailure = true
  String url
  String name = "Some name"

  WebhooksOptions(String url) {
    this.url = url
  }
}

def webHookOptions

if ("${env.BRANCH_NAME}".startsWith("PR-")) {
  webHookOptions = new WebhooksOptions("https://your-first-url")
} else {
  webHookOptions = new WebhooksOptions("https://your-second-url")
  // you can customize notification rules as well
  webHookOptions.startNotification = false
}

pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'my_node'
  }
  options {

    office365ConnectorWebhooks([[startNotification: webHookOptions.startNotification,
                                 notifySuccess: webHookOptions.notifySuccess,
                                 notifyAborted: webHookOptions.notifyAborted,
                                 notifyNotBuilt: webHookOptions.notifyNotBuilt,
                                 notifyUnstable: webHookOptions.notifyUnstable,
                                 notifyFailure: webHookOptions.notifyFailure,
                                 notifyBackToNormal: webHookOptions.notifyBackToNormal,
                                 notifyRepeatedFailure: webHookOptions.notifyRepeatedFailure,
                                 url: webHookOptions.url,
                                 name: webHookOptions.name
                                ]])
}
stages {.....}
```